# What does a call to 'this->template [somename]' do?

Tags: c++, templates

I've searched for this question and I can't find anything on it. Is there a better way to query something like this in Google or can anyone provide a link or links or a fairly detailed explanation? Thanks!

EDIT: Here's an example

```
template< typename T, size_t N>
struct Vector {
public:
   Vector() {
       this->template operator=(0);
   }

   // ...       

   template< typename U >
   typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_convertible< U, T >, Vector& >::type operator=(Vector< U, N > const & other) {
       typename Vector< U, N >::ConstIterator j = other.begin();
       for (Iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i, ++j)
           (*i) = (*j);
       return *this;
   } 
};
```

This example is from the [ndarray](http://code.google.com/p/ndarray/) project on Google Code and is not my own code.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? Please provide some code examples, your question is rather vague.

Comment: Unless he had a class which had a data member called template, but that would just be a silly thing to do.

Comment: This is not a "basic" aspect of C++.

Comment: I have to say, that is some extremely weird syntax.

Comment: @Apprentice Queue: No need to be condescending here. I simply had never come across this syntax before and was wondering how such code behaves. "this->template" is not something that is addressed when one learns classes in C++.

Comment: @cpcloud: I've updated the title of your question to better reflect the syntax (since this->template by itself doesn't technically do anything :).

Comment: @Apprentice Queue Its not that he doesn't know what `this` or a `class` is...

Comment: @cpcloud: sorry I jumped the gun too soon.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here is an example where `this->template` is required.  It doesn't really match the OP's example though:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct X
{
    template <unsigned N>
        void alloc() {std::cout << "alloc<" << N << ">()\n";}
};

template <class T>
struct Y
    : public X<T>
{
    void test()
    {
        this->template alloc<200>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Y<int> y;
    y.test();
}
```

In this example the `this` is needed because otherwise `alloc` would not be looked up in the base class because the base class is dependent on the template parameter `T`.  The `template` is needed because otherwise the "<" which is intended to open the template parameter list containing 200, would otherwise indicate a less-than sign ([temp.names]/4).

Comment: How mean, didn't get notified of your answer. :) +1 for example + standard reference.

Answer (score 1):

When extending a class that depends on a template parameter, this kind of become a `dependent name`.

The problem is that while performing `two phase name lookup`, the compiler can't know where he can find the function `hello`. He cannot know it comes from the parent. Because template specialization is a thing, `Base<int>` and `Base<double>` could be two completely different classes with different functions and members.

With the `this` keyword added, the compiler know that `hello` must be a member function.

Without that, it could be either a `member function` or `non-member function`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base {
public:

    void hello() {std::cout << "hello\n";}
    
    void hello1() {std::cout << "hello1\n";}

    template <unsigned N>
    void hello2() {std::cout << "hello2<" << N << ">()\n";}
    
};

template <class T>
class Drivered: public Base<T> {
public:
    
    using Base<T>::hello;

    void test()
    {
        hello();
        this->hello1();
        this->template hello2<200>();
 }
};
int main() {
    Drivered<int> d;
    d.test();
}
```

【1】https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667832/4268594

Answer (score 0):

It used to disambiguation, and

```cpp
// maybe: (handle->appendArray < 13) > (myarray);
handle->appendArray<13>(myarray);
```

Maybe some compilers can deduce it automatically.