# How to call pass template member method as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, `install<double>(&T::print);` could not pass compile. How could I pass `T::print` as parameter? Remove `template <typename M>` could pass compile. But I could not remove `template <typename M>`, because I need it in the true code. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
  template <typename M>
  void install(void (T::*method)(int))
  {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
class Child : public Base<T>
{
public:
  void test()
  {
    install<double>(
        &T::print);
  }
};

class Grandson : public Child<Grandson>
{
public:
  void print(int n)
  {
    std::cout << "Num:" << n << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: Related to [where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords](/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call

```
this->template install<double>(&T::print);
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/YtgtyY)

Comment: Does have any documents about `this->template`?

Comment: Oh, I find this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533354/what-does-a-call-to-this-template-somename-do