# Why isn't this an independent name?

Tags: c++, dependent-name

In class `D0` the variable `m` needs to be written as `this->m` in order to make it a dependent name that will be looked up in the base class.

But in class `D1` the compiler knows to look up `m` in the base class without `m` being written as `this->m`.

How is this possible?  Why doesn't `m` in class `D1` need to be written as `this->m`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class B
{
public:
    B(int i) : m(i) {}
    T* fb() {std::cout << "B::fb(): m = " << m << "\n"; return static_cast<T*>(this); }
protected:
    int m;
};

template<class T>
class D0 : public B<T>
{
public:
    D0(int i) : B<T>(i) {}
   /*
    * this-> makes this->m a dependent name so the lookup looks in the base class.  Without this->,
    * m would be an independent name and lookup would not check the base class.
    */
    T* fd0() {std::cout << "D0::fd0(): m = " << this->m << "\n"; return static_cast<T*>(this); }
};

class D1 : public D0<D1>
{
public:
    D1(int i) : D0<D1>(i) {}
   /*
    * D1 doesn't need m qualified by this-> because deriving from D0<D1> somehow
    * makes it unnecessary.
    */
    D1* fd1() {std::cout << "D1::fd1(): m = " << m << "\n"; return this; }
};

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    
    D1 d1(2);
    d1.fd1()->fd0()->fb()->fd0()->fd1();
    
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

Comment: Consider that `D1` is a concrete class, not a template.

Comment: Here is a related q/a, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533354/what-does-a-call-to-this-template-somename-do.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into detail, `D1` is not a class template, it is a concrete, non-templated class.  Thus there is no requirement to use `this->` to access `m`.

[Here is more information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

If you want to duplicate the error in `D1`, the following demonstrates this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class B
{
public:
    B(int i) : m(i) {}
    T* fb() {std::cout << "B::fb(): m = " << m << "\n"; return static_cast<T*>(this); }
protected:
    int m;
};

template<class T>
class D0 : public B<T>
{
public:
    D0(int i) : B<T>(i) {}
    T* fd0() {std::cout << "D0::fd0(): m = " << this->m << "\n"; return static_cast<T*>(this); }
};

template <typename T>  // Now let's make this a class template
class D1 : public D0<D1<T>>
{
public:
    D1(int i) : D0<D1>(i) {}
    D1* fd1() {std::cout << "D1::fd1(): m = " << m << "\n"; return this; } // This will now produce an error
};

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    
    D1<int> d1(2);
    d1.fd1()->fd0()->fb()->fd0()->fd1();
    
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

Error:

```
error: 'm' was not declared in this scope
     D1* fd1() {std::cout << "D1::fd1(): m = " << m << "\n"; return this; }
```

Now the error exists in `D1` once it is made a class template.

Comment: The underlying issue is that there can be a specialization of `B<Something>` that does not have a member named `m`. That's the issue in `D0`: there is no guarantee that `m` exists. In the original version of `D1`, `m` has to exist.